# Bad practice giving table cell 1 px height?

Tags: html, css, cell, tabular

I'm creating a form for which I'm using tables to create the layout. All table cells have their content aligned to the top. I've created a beautiful drawing of it here:

```
|--------------|----|
|      1       |    |
|--------------|  3 |
|              |    |
|      2       |    |
|--------------|----|
```

Cell 1 and 2 usually have more content, so they usually decide the height of the whole table. Though, sometimes cell 3 has more content - so much that it requires more height than 1 and 2, so the other cells get stretched out. That means there will be a large empty area in the bottom of cell 1.

So, I want cell 1 to have always the minimum weight, so if cell 3 stretches out the table, the extra space will place itself in the bottom of cell 3. To achieve this I gave cell 1 a height of 1px in the css. Then it'll always try to have a height of 1px, meaning it'll have the least possible height at all times.

**Is this bad practice? Does it work in all browsers?**

EDIT: Cell 3 has a 1px left border that I always want to follow the page until the bottom. This is why I'm not using divs.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to gain this shape from table because variation in each cell will enlarge the whole column
This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MohammadHamza/F3L4n/)
Instead you can try this following code.

```
<div id='column1'>
    <div class='cell1'>This is content 1</div>
    <div class='cell2'>This is content 2</div>
</div>
<div class='cell3'>This is content 3</div>
```

and the style will be

```
body
{
    width:410px;
    color:#fff;

}
div#column1 {
    float:left;
width:200px;

}
div#column1 div.cell1,div#column1 div.cell2
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#333;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
div.cell3
{
    float:right;
    display:block;
    height:400px;
    width:200px;
    background:#00b3ff;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed for your comment. I would also prefer using divs, personally I would float panel 3 to the right and apply "overflow: hidden" to the column containing div 1 and 2. Though the reason why I'm using tables is because there's a 1px border-left at cell 3. Since I don't know which column will have the most height, they have to resize together. I'll update the post about this.